# How to iterate through a list for element of URL generation

Tags: python

I am trying to grab data of census.gov - I would like to run a *for* loop that rotates through a list of months given, per the API syntax guide.

```
> # API endpoint and parameters - current pop surveys
base_url = 'https://api.census.gov/data'
year = '2023'  # Latest year of data
dataset = 'cps/basic/'  # Population and Housing estimates dataset
months = ['may', 'apr', 'mar', 'feb', 'jan'], 
get_variables = 'NAME, HEFAMINC '  # Variables aka the column headers
state = '12'  # Specify the state code for Florida
county = "*"

# List to store individual data frames
data_frames = []

# Construct the API request URL using an f-string and a for loop to cycle months for 2023
for month in months:
    url = f'{base_url}/{year}/{dataset}{month}?get={get_variables}&for=county:{county}&in=state:{state}'
    print(url)

    # Send the API request
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Check if the request was successful, otherwise print error message
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the JSON response
        data = response.json()

        # Extract the desired information
        headers = data[0]  # Column headers
        values = data[1:]  # Data values

        # Create a data frame
        df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)

        # Append the data frame to the list
        data_frames.append(df)
    else:
        print(f'Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}')

# Analyze the individual data frames further
```

When I print the URL, I am getting all elements of the list showing up, not the individual month as I had hoped:

`https://api.census.gov/data/2023/cps/basic/['may', 'apr', 'mar', 'feb', 'jan']?get=NAME, HEFAMINC &for=county:*&in=state:12`.

I am still learning Python, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the comma in the end of the line:

```
months = ['may', 'apr', 'mar', 'feb', 'jan'],
```

It makes `months` a tuple, you can see it if you print `months`:

```
(['may', 'apr', 'mar', 'feb', 'jan'],)
```

Which makes the first and only element of `months` a list `['may', 'apr', 'mar', 'feb', 'jan']`.

Get rid of the comma and the problem will be solved.

Comment: That was it. I was so close, yet so far. Thanks!

Comment: Yay! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: @labratchet Now you have to figure out why you're getting HTTP 204

Comment: @DarkKnight Ahh that was because I had not updated this chunk of code with the appropriate variables for this table from census - specifically 'NAME' does not exist for the state>county on this dataset.